# Как в CssSelector искать по позиции? Selenium, Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, selenium, dom, css-selectors

как через CssSelector в java получить второй элемент в списке? В DOM имеется порядок из элементов, где все теги имеют одинаковые атрибуты:

```
<a href="/moskva/lichnye_veschi" target="_self" class="link-link-39EVK link-design-default-2sPEv link-novisited-1w4JY category-with-counters-link-1zX0y">Личные вещи</a>

<a href="/moskva/transport" target="_self" class="link-link-39EVK link-design-default-2sPEv link-novisited-1w4JY category-with-counters-link-1zX0y">Транспорт</a>

<a href="/moskva/rabota" target="_self" class="link-link-39EVK link-design-default-2sPEv link-novisited-1w4JY category-with-counters-link-1zX0y">Работа</a>
```

Мой код:

```
    driver.get("https://www.avito.ru/moskva");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='link-link-39EVK link-design-default-2sPEv link-novisited-1w4JY category-with-counters-link-1zX0y']"));

    String par = element.getText();

    System.out.println("attribute = " + par );
```

Таким образом я получаю только тег: "личные вещи", а как например получать второй или третий, если у всех тегов одинаковые значение атрибутов? nth-of-type не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css-селекторах существ ует специальный синтаксис для работы с атрибутом `class`. Доуступ к такому атрибуту осуществляется через точку (`.`). В Вашем случае, локатор будет такой:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.link-link-39EVK.link-design-default-2sPEv.link-novisited-1w4JY.category-with-counters-link-1zX0y:nth-child(2)"));
```

[Тест](http://try.jsoup.org/%7EB26Iti2apcup5GxTF8DEZYxuHF4)